How to resume paused flow in a subtab?
I've created a LWC that represents a paused flow interview. I have a button that when clicked should resume the paused flow in a subtab. The subtab opens but a new flow interview is started. Every way I've tried to construct the url fails and I can't find documentation on what the structure and parameters need to be.
//method in another JS class and called from LWC
export const buildPausedFlowUrl = (recordId,flowApiName,interviewId) =>{
    const baseUrl = '/flow/' + flowApiName;
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
       Id: interviewId,
       recordId: recordId
    });
    console.log('Paused Flow URL: ', `${baseUrl}?${params.toString()}`);
    return `${baseUrl}?${params.toString()}`;
}
 
//method that opens subtab
async resumeFlow(event){
        let flowApiName = this.interview.InterviewLabel.split(" ")[3];
        await openFlowInSubtab(this.interview.RecordId,flowApiName,this.interview.PauseLabel,this.interview.Id);

    }

Can someone tell me the correct structure of the url OR if I'm going about this the wrong way? Thank you.
UPDATE:
I was able to figure this out by referencing the docs provided by Renato Oliveira. This youtube video was very helpful in getting subtabs to work in the first place. I created a App Page and put a LWC with a lightning_flow component on the page. @api interview is an object passed from a parent component that has the flow API name, Guid and other info needed to display the paused flow's information. resumeFlow() is an onclick handler. Clicking the button now opens a subtab with the AppPage and the LWC placed on the page resumes the flow.
Very important, for this to work myComponent must have <target>lightning__UrlAddressable</target>. Otherwise nothing happens when the button is clicked.
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { openSubtab, EnclosingTabId } from "lightning/platformWorkspaceApi";

export default class ResumePausedFlowChild extends LightningElement {
@api interview;
@wire(EnclosingTabId)parentTabId;

async resumeFlow(event){

    try {
          await openSubtab(this.parentTabId,{
            pageReference: {
              type: "standard__component",
              attributes: {
                componentName: "c__myComponent",
              },
              state: {
                c__flowInterviewId: this.interview.Guid,
                c__flowApiName: this.interview.FlowAPIName
              },
            },
            icon: "utility:sparkles",
            label: this.interview.PauseLabel,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('<<< ERROR >>>',JSON.stringify(error));
        }

}

}

Where did you get that openFlowInSubtab method?

That was a custom method I created at first in a "helper" class. It used buildPausedFlowUrl and some other methods and then called openSubtab. With the final solution I no longer use any of that. As long as the interview object passed to the component has the Guid, FlowAPIName and PauseLabel the standard openSubtab is all that's needed.
Very important, for this to work myComponent must have <target>lightning__UrlAddressable</target>. Otherwise nothing happens when the button is clicked.

As far as I am aware, the Lightning framework does not provide a way of opening a given flow in a subtab natively.
What I am pretty sure that works, given the available APIs, is that you could open a Lightning component in a subtab using the Workspace API. This way, you can pass the interview identifier as a state parameter when describing the component you want the subtab to open with, and have your LWC handle that interview ID and instantiate that screen flow interview with the lightning-flow component by defining the flow-interview-id parameter.

Thank you, Renato. Referencing the docs you shared I was able to get this working as expected without using Aura. Because I'm not sure if there's a better way and the character limit on this comment wont allow it, I'm going to update my question with what I did to get this working.

Update. I found that the LWC Recipes playground has an example of opening subtabs that has most of what you'll need to accomplish this.
